# MSI interrupt in serial driver

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, serial-port

This is a more general question:

I have a RS485 PCIe card in my system (PERICOM_PI7C9X7954). The driver for it is in [8250_pci.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_pci.c). It configures the PCIe interface. However, it doesn't use the MSI interrupt. In fact, I couldn't find any serial device that does use MSI interrupt (in 4.10 kernel).

Is there a reason for serial devices not to use MSI interrupts?
If there is an example (or anyone with experience) of MSI interrupts with serial devices - does it provide better interrupt latency?